# App built on .Net Framework 4.0 and run from Program Files (X86) will only run as admin

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am migrating a X86 app from .Net Framework 2.0 to 4.0.  It builds fine, and runs fine as long as I don't move it to Program Files (X86).  If I run it there it hangs on startup (before it gets to any of my code).  If I run it as an admin it works fine.  I read about the security changes in 4.0, but don't really see what I need to do to make this work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to Specify the Build Configuration for this.

When you make a Build Release. Make sure that it is x86 build if it is a 32 bit version.

I won't go into details about the importing your solution, and the rules of what not to do.

But based on your situation. You can't use `"Any CPU"` settings. 
So Right click the name of your application. Not the Solution.
Then Choose `Properties` Then go to `Build` Make a check on the 32Bit version as a `Prefer Target` Then Choose x86.

Then Build and Run.

This should get you the idea of the issue, about the 64bit and 32bit version.
So it is not exactly the problem of .NetFramework being Migrated, cause it is just some Libraries getting imported. But the Solution build version. Good luck.

Comment: I do build as X86.  The two odd things is that it works if I run it as admin, and also if I put it in another folder (even another folder under Program Files (X86)).  So now I'm thinking that there's something strange about the security of this particular folder.  But I don't see anything in effective permissions.  I actually cloned the sources, and then took everything out except the form itself, and I still get the same problem.